# Returning a custom object in WCF Data Services ServiceOperation

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

Is it possible to return a custom object or a generic object in a WCF Data Services ServiceOperation like :

```
public class Message {
    public string value { get; set; }
}

[WebGet]
public Message test() {
    return new Message { value = "HelloWorld!" };
}

[WebGet]
public object test2() {
    return new { message = "HelloWorld!" }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I'll post this link specifying the requirements of a Service Operation:

[Service Operations (WCF Data Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668788%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also, you can look into returning Complex Types from the Service Operation.